# Ionic 5 app not getting data from REST API on android

Tags: android, vue.js, ionic-framework, capacitor

I've built an ionic app that utilizes Vue, Capacitor and a Strapi backend deployed on heroku. I'm using the `fetch()` api to make the api calls.

The app works without errors in the browser but when complied to android and installed on my device (Android 9) I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` on the homepage where I'm using Vue's `<Suspense>` component to display an error message.

All other pages are blank and I'm unable to perform POST requests.

This is my first ionic and mobile app for that matter so I'm not sure how to debug this issue.

Comment: check this link for api calling  "https://www.djamware.com/post/5fc19e3e77862f22905c7f03/ionic-5-tutorial-oauth2-login-example-vue"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `capacitor http plugin` for API calls from a mobile device: https://github.com/capacitor-community/http
You can avoid CORS issues using this plugin, too.

In the documentation, the configuration for Android is missing, so add it like following.

1- Import and add http plugin in android\app\src\main\java\MainActivity.java

```
package com.myapp.com;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.getcapacitor.BridgeActivity;
import com.getcapacitor.Plugin;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.getcapacitor.plugin.http.Http; //added

public class MainActivity extends BridgeActivity {
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initializes the Bridge
    this.init(savedInstanceState, new ArrayList<Class<? extends Plugin>>() {{
      // Additional plugins you've installed go here
      // Ex: add(TotallyAwesomePlugin.class);
      add(Http.class); //added
    }});
  }
}
```

2- Sync gradle files in Android Studio:

```
File --> Sync Project with Gradle Files
```

In **package.json**, the dependencies should be like following:

```
"@capacitor-community/http": "^1.0.0",
"@capacitor/android": "^3.0.0",
"@capacitor/core": "^3.0.0",
```

Comment: Ani your answer helped me figure out that my build process was incomplete. I wasn't syncing gradle files in Android Studio but rather just using a CI/CD process to generate the apk.